# Draw UIView with transform into UIImage

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, screenshot, image-capture

It is easy to draw a `UIView` into a `UIImage` with `drawHierarchy(in: afterScreenUpdates:)` and `CALayer.render` methods e.g.:

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
return renderer.image { rendererContext in
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

But I want to render the `UIView` including its transform and/or its layer's transform. How can I achieve this? I need to render a `UIView` which is scaled and rotated.

One fallback solution is to render its superview into `UIImage` but for that I will have to change the UI hierarchy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround for this issue. Wrap the the `UIView` with transform into another view (without transform) with `frame` of the "transformed view". Place the transformed view at `.zero` position in the wrapper view and call `drawHierarchy(in:)` (on the wrapper view).

Or in my specific case I needed to draw text views and I ended-up drawing the texts with Core Graphics directly.

Comment: This is a great idea, thank you!